# c# Oledb excel to txt, how to also recognize letters?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have an application which uses open file dialog to open an excel file and then convert it to .txt and it works fine, almost. Currently it can only read tables with only numbers in them but I need to add a function so that it could also read letters. What should I change to make it able to read letters/words as well as numbers?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnFileOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        var result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
        switch (result)
        {
            case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK:
                var file = fileDialog.FileName;
                TxtFile.Text = file;
                TxtFile.ToolTip = file;
                break;
            case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel:
            default:
                TxtFile.Text = null;
                TxtFile.ToolTip = null;
                break;
        }

    }

    public void convert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Configure save file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Save document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            exportExcelToTxt(TxtFile.Text, filename);
        }

    }
    static void exportExcelToTxt(string excelFilePath, string outputTxtPath)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<long>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<long>>();
        using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\"", excelFilePath)))
        {
            excelConnection.Open();
            string firstSheet = getFirstSheetName(excelConnection);
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = excelConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheet);
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt); // Getting all the data in the sheet
                        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            List<long> toAdd = new List<long>();
                            string key = item[0] as string;
                            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                            {
                                toAdd.Add(Convert.ToInt64(item[i]));
                            }
                            values.Add(key, toAdd); // Associating all the "numbers" to the "Name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        StringBuilder toWriteToTxt = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<long>> item in values)
        {
            // Formatting the output
            toWriteToTxt.Append(string.Format("{0}:", item.Key));
            foreach (long val in item.Value.Distinct())
            {
                toWriteToTxt.AppendFormat("\t{0} * {1}\r\n", item.Value.Where(f => f == val).Count(),  // Amount of occurrencies of each number
                    val);
            }
        }
        // Writing the TXT
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputTxtPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.Write(toWriteToTxt.ToString());
            }
        }
    }


    static string getFirstSheetName(OleDbConnection excelConnection)
    {
        using (DataTable ExcelTables = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" }))
        {
            return ExcelTables.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You've already loaded the data to a DataTable, why do you copy it to a List as well?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought I needed to do that to count the amount of occurencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should not convert the values to long in this line:

```
toAdd.Add(Convert.ToInt64(item[i]));
```

Also replace all `List<long>` with `List<string>`, this should cover pretty much the issue.

Comment: You mean I should remove the `toAdd` line?

Comment: No, just use something like toAdd.Add(item[i]);

Comment: I changed all the `List<long>` to ´List<string>` and changed the line to the one you suggested. It now gives me this error: `"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments"`

Comment: Use  toAdd.Add(item[i].ToString())

Comment: The next line `values.Add(key, toAdd);` gives an error: `Value cannot be null`